# Ignore spaces with jquery ui autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Referring to http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Is there a way to allow for searches such as:

```
A B C
```

or

```
ABC
```

to return the same results, either way.

---

My client has data which use alternating variations of the following for example:

```
A & B shoe company
```

and

```
A&B shoes co
```

---

Their users expect the jquery ui autocomplete combobox to bring up either when they type one of the following:

```
A & B
```

and

```
A&B
```

---

Legacy applications have allowed them this before and resultingly they have become accustomed to "expediting" their searches by sometimes excluding spaces, or other times "forgetting" to put in spaces in data such as the above.

Their current web based application makes extensive use of the jquery ui autocomplete combobox, so the intention is not to remove it and replace with some proprietary widget.

I am currently looking at modifying the actual jquery.ui.combobox.js source, but prefer to find a recommended or at least more elegant method to achieve this.